# which code is better ? and how do we understand that ? why is the final print function in the second code sometimes printing random numbers?

Tags: c

I am very new here .. so please excuse me if my question is really unnecessary .. but I think the answer will help me have some faith in myself ..here are two code snippets ..one i got on the website c4learn.com ..

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main() 
{    
   char s1[100], s2[100];    
   int i;      

   printf("\nEnter the string :");   
   gets(s1);     
   i = 0;   
   while (s1[i] != '\0') 
        {       
          s2[i] = s1[i];     
            i++;   
        }      
   s2[i] = '\0';   
   printf("\nCopied String is %s ", s2);     

   return (0); 
}
```

and the other i wrote myself  ..

```
#include<stdio.h>  

int main() 
{   
   char s1[100], s2[100];   
   int i;       
   printf("\n Enter the string 1");     
   gets(s1);        
   printf("\n Enter the string2");  
   gets(s2);        


   for(i=0;i<100;i++)   
     {      
           if (s1[i]!='\0')     
            {           
              s2[i]=s1[i];          
            }           
      }     
   s2[i]='\0';  

   printf("\n Copied string is %s ", s2);       

   return(0);``
 }
```

the problem is while running the code on dev c++ .. the final printf displayed is showing some random characters at the end of the string .. Can anyone help me understand that and which is code is better ? the initial question was ... HOW WILL YOU COPY ONE STRING TO ANOTHER WITHOUT USING ANY INBUILT LIBRARIES ? thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not quite right:

- Why do you ask for the user input for s2 if you then overwrite it, copying s1?
- The for cycle you wrote doesn't stop when s1 is over (I mean the null terminator character `'\0'`) so you are also copying all the chars remaining in s1 after `'\0'`. If the chars in the array are not initialized (and that's the case for chars after `'\0'`) they of course might result in random characters.

So answering your question, the first code is the right way to do it.

Any way if you want to use a for cycle you could do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    s2[i] = s1[i];
    if (s1[i] == '\0') 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to break out of the loop when you reach the null terminator character `\0`. The first code breaks out of the while loop while you're code continues on until `i == 100` skipping over the null character. This is why its printing garbage past the original string.

This is what you should do to break out after the null character.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  s2[i] = s1[i];
  if (s1[i] == '\0') break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second block of code, after exiting the `for` loop, `i` has a value of 100.  So you're putting the `0` byte at index 100.

Since an array of size 100 has indexes 0 to 99, you're writing past the end of the array.  That causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you're inside of the `for` loop, you need to `break` out after you find the null byte.

Also, both programs use `gets` which is unsafe because it does not perform any bounds checking and may write past the end of the array.